# How can you tell if your sink is compatible with a portable washer?

Tags: sink, clothes-washer

I'm looking to get a portable washer, but I'm not sure if I'll be able to attach the washer to the sink facet. Is there a standard that portable washers adhere to? If so, how do you tell you have a facet that is that standard?

Answer (score 1):

Most portable dishwashers use a quick-disconnect fitting that attaches to the threaded spout of a faucet. There are adapters available to allow attachment to virtually any faucet spout (with the exception of maybe a tub spout or an un-threaded spigot).